# Files are empty after copying it to the S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an S3 bucket called `source-bucket-6` and I write a lambda function to copy files from the lambda location to the S3 bucket.

[image]

As you see in the screenshot, here we have two files `Index.html` and `Test.txt`. I just want to copy those files to the S3 bucket. But whenever I try to copy them to the bucket, I see both files are empty and there's no content in the files. Here's my lambda code:

```
import boto3
import os

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
cwd = os.getcwd()


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = 'source-bucket-6'


    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    for f in files:
        if f != "lambda_function.py":
            s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=f)
            print(f"------------------{f} ")
        
    print("Put Completed")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `put_object` command is not specifying any content for the object.

If you want to **upload a file**, use:

```py
s3.upload_file(Filename=f, Bucket=bucket, Key=f)
```

where `f` is the **filename** of the file to upload.

Comment: But I want to copy the file not upload it. So, why I should use `upload_file`?

Comment: Please tell us more about what you consider "copy" to mean -- from where is the data coming and to where is the data going? If it is coming from a file within an AWS Lambda function and is going to an Amazon S3 bucket, then this is equivalent to an `upload_file()` operation because it is going from a local file to an S3 bucket in the cloud.

Comment: Both files are in the cloud not locally. That's why I ask.

Comment: You can "copy" files between two Amazon S3 buckets, but if you want to "copy files from the lambda location to the S3 bucket" then you would use `upload_file()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing [Body](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object.html) argument. It should be:

```
s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=f, Body=open(f, 'r'))
```

Comment: I received an error message saying `"errorMessage": "Strings must be encoded before hashing"`